# How could I create unique node with py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Suppose I need to create unique node with **email**,

If I run the following code, it will creat 2 nodes with the same **email**

```
person_nod = Node("person", email="bob123@gmail.com")
graph.create(person_nod)

person_nod = Node("person", email="bob123@gmail.com")
graph.create(person_nod)
```

I have no idea how to avoid the duplicated node with **neo4j**

Answer (score 9):

First, if you want unique nodes, you should create a uniqueness constraint on label `person` and property `email`:

```
graph = Graph()
graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint('person', 'email')
```

Now you will get an error if you try to add a node that violates the uniqueness constraint. I.e. your second create statement will fail.

You can also merge the node instead of creating it. `MERGE` matches existing nodes or creates them if they do not exist:

```
person_node = graph.merge('person', property_key='email', property_value='email@email.com')
```

For merging see: http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#py2neo.Graph.merge